# loading 400 k of records from Oracle tables into ElasticSearch via logstash, having issues

Tags: java, oracle, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Am loading Oracle records into elasticsearch via logstash. I have created `Full outer join` in between 5 tables having relationship between eachother. After joining all the five tables, number of record count come as `300403` but, after the records are loaded in ElasticSearch from elasticsearch it shows as `367673`.
Number of record count also increased in elasticsearch.

Following is my structure of records in Oracle that am loading into ElasticSearch.

```
id      link_id         code            Type
1001    2001            ABC-123         Reg
1002    2002            ABC-345         Reg
1003    2003            ABC-123         Act
1004    2004            ABC-123         Reg
```

Here some of the `id`s are inserted as `null` in ElasticSearch. For example

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 9,
    "max_score": 12.906438,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "replacement",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "VizyEWQB3JLlyWOUWyyY",
        "_score": 12.906438,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2018-06-18T08:10:53.037Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "link_id": 2001,
          "type": null,
          "id": null,   // ----> this is have some value in oracle DB
          "code": "ABC-123",
         }
      },
```

Please find my logstash config file

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\1SearchEngine\data\ojdbc8.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1525:XE"     
    jdbc_user => "demo"
    jdbc_password => "abc2011"
    statement => "select * from product
                    FULL OUTER JOIN product_link
                    ON product.id=product_link.product_id
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "replacement"
  }
}
```

Please find my actual mapping file.

```
{
  "replacement": {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "catalog_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "catalog_product_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "code": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
          },
          "company_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "country_id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "expiration_date": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "is_visible": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "link_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "min_order_quantity": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "product_group": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "product_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "product_type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "rank": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "region_id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "std_delivery_time": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "vendor_id": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide index mapping? Looks like you have some nested fields, that are counted separately.

Comment: @VadimBeskrovnov - i have updated my actual mapping file in my question.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the IDs are being repeated. when logstash encounters an ID again it will add a new record and not override earlier one. Try adding `order by product.id` at the end of SQL query and change the pipeline.workers to `1` so it processes the IDs in sequence.

Comment: One more thing, you have not specified an `id` for logstash so it will create its own. Add this line in `output` `document_id => "%{id}"` so it will avoid duplicates and will use your database id as the document id